# Impossible to make my compass move (orientation sensor in Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, sensors

I'm trying to implement a compass that use the sensor orientation. I followed a lot of different tutorials but everytime, I can't make my compass move.

Here is the code of my best try :

My MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.sha8.compas;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.hardware.Sensor;
        import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
        import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
        import android.hardware.SensorManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.animation.Animation;
        import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

   public ImageView imgCompass;


    public float currentDegree = 0f;
    public SensorManager sensorManager;

    TextView txtDegrees;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgCompass=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgCompass);
        txtDegrees=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDegrees);
        sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
        float degree=Math.round(event.values[0]);
        txtDegrees.setText("Rotation: "+Float.toString(degree)+" degrees");
        RotateAnimation ra=new RotateAnimation(currentDegree,-degree,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
        ra.setDuration(120);
        ra.setFillAfter(true);
        imgCompass.startAnimation(ra);
        currentDegree=-degree;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor p1, int p2)
    {
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtDegrees"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgCompass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDegrees"
        android:src="@drawable/img_compass" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sha8.compas">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If you have some hint to help me make it work or understand where is the problem, I thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked here:  https://github.com/iutinvg/compass/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sevencrayons/compass/Compass.java

Comment: Yes I checked and I already tried this one. If you see the manifest, he doesn't allowed the sensor orientation, and I downloaded the app and nothing moved (it was a static compass).

Comment: did you tried this https://github.com/iutinvg/compass